# Audio thread running slow while using animation

Tags: android, audio, animation, service

I am using a service to run a background music for the whole application.
The service stars an Async task to play the audio file.
For activities in which there is no animation, the music is running good.
but for activities which have animations the music keeps on breaking or could say running slow (I hope I am able to express).

I don't understand what is the problem because everything is running fine except for the audio only in those particular screen

Is this because I'm using emulator and in real device it will work? 
or is there a way to get this done in emulator to.

thank you for answering.

Comment: Try it on a real device.

Comment: should i try running animations in separate thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that solved this problem

1. Using AmimationDrawable instead of AnimationUtils class (Flickering of audio only while navigating )
2. Increasing the heap size of avd(even that small flickering was eliminated after this)

Answer (score 0):

Run your animations in a seperate thread. This would help, but make sure you use handlers. Because the views can only changed from its original thread.

Do it on this way:

```
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    (new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do long calculations here
            myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                  //set your views here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })).start();
```

Comment: Yes I got it working in emulator itself other way around and its running good in real device, smoother than emulator.
I would be pasting the procedure within a day for others too.

Comment: I was using animation to show blink effect in an `imageview` by using `AnimationUtils` and using `set` in drawable used. This was giving problem.
so instead of using that, `animation-lists` serves the purpose by using two images one with alpha 100 and other with alpha 0.